# Swift Not Presenting All text Within Text Field

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am querying information from the parse database, and want to display all the data in a text field. My code prints everything into the output box, however the actual iOS simulator only displays one piece of the entire data. Would appreciate any suggestions!

```
@IBOutlet var Groupnames: UITextView!

@IBAction func QueryDataAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "BeaterGroups")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && object != nil {

            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {

                for objects in object {

                    println(objects.valueForKey("GroupName")!)
                    let groupname = objects.valueForKey("GroupName") as! String
                    self.Groupnames.text = groupname

                }

            }

        }



    }

 }
```

Comment: What is your output log. paste it with your question

Comment: try to show your data in textView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably only getting the text for the last object.  You need to append to the text, not assign to it.

For example, initialize the text field to "" prior to entering the loop, then change the assignment line as follows as in this excerpt:

```
self.Groupnames.text = ""
for objects in object {
    println(objects.valueForKey("GroupName")!)
    let groupname = objects.valueForKey("GroupName") as! String
    self.Groupnames.text = self.Groupnames.text + groupname + " "
}
```

This will separate the objects with a space; you can change the separator if you wish.

Comment: Yes, it is only showing the last piece. So, how could I append this data?

Comment: See if the latest addition works, if not we can probably adjust.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. Tells me that binary operands can't be applied to two string operands, (+=) operation is the issue.

Comment: As long as self.Groupnames.text is a string, the following should work instead: 


self.Groupnames.text = self.Groupnames.text + groupname + " "